# Creating Blazor component similar to Response.Write

Tags: blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a component similar to Response.Write("") back in the day for helping me diagnose Blazor lifecycle issues. This is what I have so far, but nothing is printing to the UI. However, when I remove the component and directly write to the UI, I get no problems.

```
<div>
    @foreach (string line in Lines)
    {
        <div>@line</div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<string> Lines
    {
        get
        {
            return _lines;
        }
        set
        {
            _lines = value;
        }
    }
```

In my page component I have an instance of the Debug component like:

```
<Debug @ref="LocalDebug" />

@code {
    protected Debug LocalDebug { get; set }

    protected void Function() {
        Debug.Lines.Add("Print something");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You doing it in a wrong way, you can achieve functionality like this

This is your Debug.razor component

```
<div>
    @foreach (string line in Lines)
    {
        <div>@line</div>
    }
</div>

@code {

    private List<string> Lines = new();

    public void AddLine(string line){
        Lines.Add(line);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

This is how you can use it in razor page

```
<Debug @ref="LocalDebug" />
```

This is code behind in razor page

```
@code {
    private Debug LocalDebug;
    
    protected void Function() {
        LocalDebug.AddLine("Add something");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I try to LocalDebug.AddLine("test message");

Comment: Could you please let me know the part of code where you are trying LocalDebug.AddLine

Comment: on any local function, similar to what you have

Comment: If you try it in OnInitialized then it won't work, you can use it in OnAfterRender or any other function, alternatively could you please share the complete code you are trying